# Comparison of bool data types in C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

The `bool` data type is commonly represented as `0` (as `false`) and `1` (as `true`). However, some say that `true` values can be represented by a value other than `1`. If the later statement is `true`, then the following expression may be incorrect.

```
bool x = 1;
if (x==1)
    Do something..
```

I am wondering if the following statements would work as desired and expected on commonly used compilers.

1. ```
   bool x = 1;
   if (x==1)
       Do something.
   ```
2. ```
   bool y = 0;
   if (y>0.5)
       Do something..
   ```
3. ```
   bool z = 1;
   if(z>0.5)
       Do something...
   ```

Comment: [This implicit conversion reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) might be helpful to read.

Comment: According to the boolean conversions rules: "The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become false. All other values become true."

Comment: The conversions to and from `bool` do not depend on how a `bool` is represented. Your code will work even if `true` is represented as 39 and `false` as 10003.

Comment: My gut feeling is that there's something deeper behind this question. Maybe not about the *implicit conversions*, which can be looked up and argued about based on the spec, but rather about the "actual representation". Maybe what happens during hacky contortions along the lines of `double x = *(reinterpret_cast<double*>>(&someBool));` (i.e. when brutally exposing the actual representation - not sure about the exact syntax from the tip of my head, or whether it causes UB at some point...)

Comment: Re, "I am wondering if the following statements would work as desired..." That depends on what you desire. If `y` is a bool variable, and you write `if(y){...}` then your desire is obvious to anybody who reads your code. If, on the other hand, you write `if(y>0.5){...}` That's somewhat of a head scratcher. The reader can consult the C language standard to see what _it_ says about the construct, but that still won't tell the reader what _you_ intended.

Comment: FWIW, it's looking likely that [this paper](http://wg21.link/p0907) will make its way into the standard, at which point 0 and 1 will be the only allowed representations of true and false.

Comment: What exactly is the hindrance to using `true` and `false`? I mean, pretty much the whole purpose of a `bool` type is to be a "boolean", not a "number", from an imaginary/theoretical point of view (even though it is technically a number, and converts to a number). Otherwise you could just as well use `char` with the values `0` and `1`.

Comment: @Damon The only example I can think of from the top of my head is using a bool to index into an array which is at least less code and possibly more efficient if the compiler isn't good.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

§4.5 of the [C++ standard](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/isocppstd/conv.html) says:

> An rvalue of type bool can be
>   converted to an rvalue of type int,
>   with false becoming zero and true
>   becoming one.

regarding 2 and 3, type conversion takes place so the statements will work as desired

Comment: Where is this quotation from?

Comment: @Brian: C++ is formally documented by an ISO standard (14882). So on Stack Overflow, such quotations that omit the source document are assumed to reference the _then-current_ C++ Standard. As this is a 2019 answer, that means the quote is  from ISO 14882:2017 (aka C++17).

Comment: @MSalters I know for a fact this is not from ISO 14882:2017.

Comment: I suspect it's from the *C++03 standard*, but I don't have a copy handy to check.

Comment: This text only specifies what the conversion does, not when it is applied. Some of OP's examples convert bool to float, not bool to int.  The specification for each operator specifies which conversions are applicable to that situation.

Answer (score 9):

According to the rule of [Boolean conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Boolean_conversions):

> A prvalue of integral, floating-point, unscoped enumeration, pointer,
>   and pointer-to-member types can be converted to a prvalue of type
>   `bool`.
>
> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped
>   enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member
>   values become `false`. All other values become `true`.

Then

```
bool x = 1; // x will be true
bool y = 0; // y will be false
bool z = 1; // z will be true
```

For the 1st case, `if (x==1)`, `x` will be [promoted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to `int`,

> the type `bool` can be converted to `int` with the value `false` becoming ​`0`​ and `true` becoming `1`.

then `(x==1)` is `true`.

For the second case, `if (y>0.5)`, `y` will be promoted to `int` with value `0`, then [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) to `double` for the [comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators);

> If the operands has arithmetic or enumeration type (scoped or unscoped), usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands following the rules for arithmetic operators. The values are compared after conversions:

and

> If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral or unscoped enumeration type, then before any other action (but after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, if applicable), the operand undergoes integral promotion.
>
> ...
>
> - Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted to `double`

then `y>0.5` is `false`.

For the third case, `if (z>0.5)`, `z` will be promoted to `int` with value `1`, then [converted](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions) to `double` for the [comparison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators); then `z>0.5` is `true`.

Comment: "y will be promoted to int with value 0" - this is incorrect. `y` will be converted to `double`. As covered by your quote "Otherwise, if either operand is `double`, the other operand is converted to `double`".  (`>` is not an arithmetic operator). Same goes for `z`

Comment: @M.M Shouldn't *integral promotion* be performed firstly? As I quoted "If the operand passed to an arithmetic operator is integral ... then before any other action ... the operand undergoes integral promotion."

Comment: `>` is not an arithmetic operator

Comment: @M.M Yes, but I think [the rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison#Arithmetic_comparison_operators) is the same. "If the operands has arithmetic or enumeration type (scoped or unscoped), usual arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands following the rules for arithmetic operators. The values are compared after conversions:"

Comment: Your quote in your last comment is correct, and the behaviour of "usual arithmetic conversions" is quoted in your answer, namely "Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other operand is converted to double"

Answer (score 6):

`if (x==1)` is not incorrect. All true value representations are converted to 1 when you convert a boolean to a numeric type.

Given `bool z=true`, `if(z>0.5)` will be true, because 1.0 is greater than 0.5.

Comment: *"not incorrect"* - [double negative](https://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/media.blubrry.com/grammargirl/traffic.libsyn.com/grammar/gg_666.mp3)

Comment: even if casting is possible I think we should not do that. We should explicitly compare variable of right same type even if it is more verbose. I see some compilation error which raise up for those cases

Answer (score 4):

`bool` has only two values, and they are `true` and `false`. `1` and `0` are integer literals and as such they can be converted to `bool`. You have to consider that the conversion works in both directions, but you do not necessarily get back the same integer:

```
int a = 5;
bool b = a; // int -> bool conversion
int c = b;  // bool -> int conversion
std::cout << a << " " c;
```

prints:

```
5 1
```

Any integer value other than `0` gets converted to `true`, but `true` gets always converted to `1`.

Keeping this in mind, all your examples will work as expected. However, note that `bool`s main purpose is that we can use `true` and `false` in our code instead of having to give numbers as `0` and `1` special meaning. It is always better to be explicit, so when you mean `true` you better write `true` not `1`.

Answer (score 0):

A relevant question here is "why do we even allow comparison between a `bool` and an `int`?".

The answer is backward compatibility and compromise, because C and C++ used to recommend integers to store Boolean values. So there was a lot of code that

1. Should keep working in spite of new language rules, such that
   relational operators return a bool instead of an int.
2. Allow you to upgrade old code by changing the declaration of a Boolean variable
   with a minimum of follow-up changes in the rest of the code.

Other languages may be cleaner in this respect, but the `bool` type has apparantly been a success.